# Open another Excel Workbook - Automatic Calculation

Tags: vba, excel

In one of my major excel files, there is a vba code that I use to call other excel sheets from other files.
Since my main file started to slow down, I wanted to add a simple code in Workbook module to make it open with "CalculationManual" and then close it with "CalculationAutomatic" and everything works fine.

But, when I try to call other sheets from other files, in vba, it first changes the automation to Automatic, but doesn't open the selected workbook, and after the error, I see that calculation is again at Manual.

Here are the codes from Workbook;

```
Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Call Dijital_Off
    Application.CellDragAndDrop = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
Sub Workbook_Open()
Worksheets("Acilis").Activate
Worksheets("Acilis").Range("A1").Select
    Application.CellDragAndDrop = True
Worksheets("Acilis").ScrollArea = "A1:B2"
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End Sub
```

This is the opening of the code which I use to call other workbooks;

```
    Sub Storyboard_Ekle()

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

    Worksheets("Egitim Bilgileri").Unprotect Password:="**$#Bildircin'A1313XQ.;**"
    Worksheets("Egitim Bilgileri").Visible = True
    Worksheets("Kunye").Unprotect Password:="**$#Bildircin'A1313XQ.;**"
    Worksheets("Acilis").Visible = True
    Worksheets("Yonetim").Unprotect Password:="**$#Bildircin'A1313XQ.;**"

        Dim DosyaSec As Office.FileDialog

        Set DosyaSec = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

       With DosyaSec

          .AllowMultiSelect = False
          .Title = "Lütfen yeni eklenecek Storyboard dosyasini seçiniz."
          .Filters.Clear
          .Filters.Add "Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook", "*.xlsm"
          .Filters.Add "Excel Workbook", "*.xlsx"
          .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"

          If .Show = True Then
            YeniSB = .SelectedItems(1)
            Else: GoTo Son
          End If

    Dim YeniStoryBoard As Workbook
    Dim AnaDosya As Workbook
    Dim YeniStoryBoard_Sheet As Worksheet
    Dim AnaDosya_Sheet As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set AnaDosya = ThisWorkbook
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False


    Dim Yeni_Sheet As String

Set YeniStoryBoard = Workbooks.Open(YeniSB)

YeniStoryBoard.Worksheets("Storyboard").Visible = True
YeniStoryBoard.Worksheets("Storyboard").Unprotect Password:="**$#Bildircin'A1313XQ.;**"

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Kunye").Visible = True
YeniStoryBoard.Worksheets("Storyboard").Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Kunye")
```

I get:

> "Run-time error 1004, Method 'Open' of objects 'Workbooks' failed" error,

I get the error at `Set YeniStoryboard = Workbooks.Open(YeniSB)` since the codes doesn't open the YeniSB storyboard when I implemented the automation.

Comment: On which line is the error?

Comment: I get the error at "Set YeniStoryboard = Workbooks.Open(YeniSB)" since the codes doesn't open the YeniSB storyboard when I implemented the automation.

Comment: If you write `MsgBox YeniSB` on the line before the error, what do you get?

Comment: It gave me the link of the excel file that I wanted to open, and then gave me the same error.

Comment: How was the link looking like? If you open a new Excel application, select `file>open>browse` and write that **exact**  link to be opened what would happen?

Comment: It opens the excel file. There is no problem with opening the file itself. If I delete the automation codes from the workbook codes and the codes to call a workbook, everything works fine. The link is: "Q:\Users\m_mermer\My Documents\Check1.xlsm "

Comment: I see. If you delete about 90% of your code, can you shorten it only to the lines, openning the excel file and giving the error?Make sure that these give exactly that error. This is called [mcve] and it would help quite a lot to others to help you.

Comment: Well I tried everything after implementing the automation process, and no matter what I do, I cannot call another excel file, and I was using that codes for like a year with no problem. Just opened the excel with automation at manual, turn it back to automatic with inside the vba and boom, no more workbooks opening.

Comment: I see. However, it would really help a lot, if you delete the first 40 lines of `Storyboard_Ekle()` and make sure that you are getting the same exact error. You would Probably get some worthy answers.

Comment: The problem may be an attempt to reopen a file while DisplayAlerts are disabled. Enable DisplayAlerts for the sake of troubleshooting. I might help.